# Find basis for new coordinate matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $ L: \Bbb{R}^{4} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^{3} $ be a linear map with matrix $$ M_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4 & 7 & 10 \\
2 & 5 & 8 & 11 \\
3 & 6 & 9 & 12
\end{pmatrix} $$

with respect to the standard basis of $ \Bbb{R}^{4} $ and $ \Bbb{R}^{3} $ respectively. I am asked to find two basis $ B_{1} $ of $ \Bbb{R}^{4} $ and $ B_{2} $ of $ \Bbb{R}^{3} $ such that the matrix of $ L $ with respect to this basis is $$ M_{2}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} $$

I tried doing elementary row operations on $ M_{1} $ to end up with $ M_{2} $ but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You probably have to use columns operations as well in order to obtain $M_2$.  Row operations correspond to changing the basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$; column operations correspond to changing the basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to do is to solve the system$$M_1.\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$That is easy and you get $a=c + 2 d$ and $b=-2 c - 3 d$. So, taking $c=1$ and $d=0$ and taking $c=0$ and $d=1$, you get the vectors$$v_3=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }v_4=\begin{pmatrix}2\\-3\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$$respectively. Now, let$$v_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }v_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$which are linearly independent vectors and none of them is a linear combination of $v_3$ and $v_4$. Let $w_1=M_1.v_1$ and $w_2=M_1.v_2-M_1.v_1$. Then$$w_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }w_2=\begin{pmatrix}3\\3\\3\end{pmatrix}.$$ Find a vector $w_3\in\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and note that $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Then

- $M_1.v_1=w_1$;
- $M_1.v_2=w_1+w_2$;
- $M_1.v_3=0$;
- $M_1.v_4=0$

and therefore these are the bases that you are looking for.

Comment: I see you've beat me to it.  Excellent answer, +1.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is certainly a mechanical approach to this problem involving row-operations and echelon form, but I think you will find it far more instructive to approach this problem by applying the definitions.

Suppose that $B_1 = \{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$, and $B_2 = \{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$.  The form of $M_2$ tells us that
$$
L(v_1) = w_1\\
L(v_2) = w_1 + w_2\\
L(v_3) = 0\\
L(v_4) = 0
$$
To that end, you can approach the problem as follows:

- Find a basis $\{v_3,v_4\}$ of $\ker L$, i.e. the nullspace of $M_1$.
- Choose any $v_1$ outside of this kernel, and take $w_1 = L(v_1)$.
- Choose a $v_2$ to complete the basis $\{v_1,v_3,v_4\}$, and take $w_2 = L(v_2) - w_1$.
- Choose a $w_3$ to complete the basis $\{w_1,w_2\}$.