# Find basis for another coordinate matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

This is related to my previous question:
[Find basis for new coordinate matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2561448/find-basis-for-new-coordinate-matrix)

I am asked again to find basis of $ \Bbb{R}^{4} $ and $ \Bbb{R}^{3} $ such that the matrix of $ L $ with respect to these basis is
$$ M_{3}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} $$

but I think this is not possible as if such basis $ \{ v_{1},v_{2},v_{3},v_{4} \} $ and $ \{ w_{1},w_{2},w_{3}\} $ would exist then we would have $$ M_{1}v_{1}=w_{1} $$ 
$$ M_{1}v_{2}=w_{1}+w_{2} $$ 
$$ M_{1}v_{3}=w_{1} $$ 
$$ M_{1}v_{4}=w_{2} $$ 
We choose $ v_{3} $ and $ v_{4} $ just as in the previous example i.e. such that $ <v_{3},v_{4}>=ker(L) $ and let  $ v_{1},v_{2} $ be two other linear independent vectors in $ \Bbb{R}^{4} $ not contained in $ <v_{3},v_{4}> $. Then we have $$ M_{1}(v_{1}-v_{3})=w_{1}-w_{1}=0 $$ so it would mean that $ v_{1} \in <v_{3},v_{4}> $, absurd. 
Am I missing something or is this correct? I would appreciate any comments. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, there is no reason to take $v_3,v_4\in\ker L$. Actually, you know that they *will not be* in $\ker L$, since $M_1.v_3=w_1\neq0$ and that $M_1.v_4=w_2\neq0$.

Comment: You are absolutely right. What I know is that $ v_{1}-v_{3},v_{2}-v_{1}-v_{4} $ and $ v_{2}-v_{1}-v_{4} $ are in the kernel so I guess I should work that out. Thank you very much for pointing out my stupid mistake.

Comment: @Raizen I'm glad I could help.